# Proving $\small\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left( \sin (\ln(x+1))-\sin(\ln(x)) \right)$

Tags: calculus

I can't calculate this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\sin(\ln(x+1))-\sin(\ln(x))$ Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Use the identity $$\sin a-\sin b=2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

For any $x,y$, you have

$$\left\vert \sin x - \sin y\right\vert \le \left\vert x-y \right\vert$$

Hence the limit you’re looking for is equal to $0$ as

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \ln (x+1) - \ln x =0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Applying the formula $\sin c - \sin d = 2\cos(\frac{c+d}{2})\sin(\frac{c-d}{2}),$

$$2\cos\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+x)+\ln x}{2}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln x}{2}\bigg)$$

$$2\cos\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+x)+\ln x}{2}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}{2}\bigg)$$

Now, applying limit as x approaches $\infty$,

$\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ approaches $0$ and $\sin(\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ also approaches $0$.

And, $-1<\cos\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+x)+\ln x}{2}\bigg)<1$

Overall, the whole thing goes to $0$.

So,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(\ln(1+x)) - \sin(\ln x) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof that the limit equals $0$ which doesn't use anything about the $\sin$ function *except* that it is uniformly continuous.

First a preliminary calculation:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) = \ln\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{x}\right) = \ln(1) = 0
$$

So then, given $\epsilon > 0$ we must find $N > 0$ and use it to prove that if $x > N$ then $$| \sin(\ln(x+1)) - \sin(\ln(x)) | < \epsilon$$

The function $\sin(x)$ is uniformly continuous. So using the given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$ such that if $|a-b| < \delta$ then $|\sin(a)-\sin(b)| < \epsilon$. We may therefore choose $N$ so that if $x \ge N$ then $|\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)| < \delta$, and it follows that $|\sin(\ln(x+1)) - \sin(\ln(x))| < \epsilon$.